# What was in his shoe?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-man-who-killed-hitler

In [The Man Who Killed Hitler and Then The Bigfoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Killed_Hitler_and_Then_the_Bigfoot) the old version of the character keeps stopping to shake something out of his shoe.  Nothing comes out.

Near the end of the movie he finally shakes it out and picks it up.  I feel like I blinked for a second because I missed what that thing was.  Does the movie tell you what was in his shoe?